# List of years for ui.Select

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to list all image available years of image collection and use it as an item for `ui.Select`. I have tried to figure out a code for it, but it is not working. Is anyone can help me to improve it?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI')};

var allDates = ee.List(collection.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(ee.Date(date).format('YYYY')).millis();
  }).distinct();  
print(allDatesSimple);


var year_select = ui.Select({
  items: allDatesSimple.getInfo(),
  onChange: function(value) {
  var year_number = value
  },
  style: {width: '200px'}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the date as a year (`ee.Date(date).get('year')`), wrap it in `ee.Algorithms.String()` to convert year integer to string.

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI');

var allDates = ee.List(collection.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Algorithms.String(ee.Date(date).get('year'));
  }).distinct();  

var year_select = ui.Select({
  items: allDatesSimple.getInfo(),
  onChange: function(value) {
    var year_number = value;
    print(year_number);
  },
  style: {width: '200px'}
});

print(year_select);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b18e0435a4d59730c460c8561f7fd16?as_external)